# Why does PCA work well while the total variance retained is small?

Tags: machine-learning, principal-component-analysis

I'm learning machine learning by looking through other people's kernel on Kaggle, specifically this [Mushroom Classification kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/raghuchaudhary/mushroom-classification/data).

The author first applied PCA to the transformed indicator matrix. He only used 2 principal components for visualization later. Then I checked how much variance it has maintained, and found out that only 16% variance is maintained.

```
in [18]: pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()
out[18]: array([0.09412961, 0.16600686])
```

But the test result with 90% accuracy suggests it works well.

If variance stands for information, then how can the ML model work well when so much information is lost?

Answer (score 0):

Because it selects both `Xtrain` and `Xtest` from the space of two selected principal components. Hence, the 90% accuracy is in that 2-D selected space.

This fact that the ratio in PCA stands the information, depends on the distribution of the data and it's not true at all.